# How to shrink sparse files in same way as rsync does in linux after copied them without "-S" operator?

Tags: linux, rsync, sparsefile

I try to take a backup of a disk.
I use `rsync` to backup files between disks.

However, while used `--delete` option in `rsync` alone and then backup, destination disk is almost full while source not.

By examining sparse files in both disks, using

```
find . -type f -printf "%S\t%p\n" | gawk '$1 < 0.8 {print}'
```

I found out that sparse files in source disks are "shrinked" while this is not true in destination disk.

I used already `rsync`, and many sparse files have been copied already. How I can shrink them in order to occupy same space as in source disk?

Sadly, I didn't use the `-S` operator with `rsync`.

I know I can delete them and copy them again...

Comment: "as rsync does in linux" – Does this mean your OS is Linux? Or are you just comparing to Linux's `rsync`? What is your OS?

Comment: Linux, debian is my OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The tool

Use `fallocate -d filename`.

> `-d`, `--dig-holes`
> Detect and dig holes. This makes the file sparse in-place, without using extra disk space. The minimum size of the hole depends on filesystem I/O block size (usually 4096 bytes). Also, when using this option, `--keep-size` is implied. If no range is specified by `--offset` and `--length`, then the entire file is analyzed for holes.
>
> You can think of this option as doing a `cp --sparse` and then renaming the destination file to the original, without the need for extra disk space.
>
> See `--punch-hole` for a list of supported filesystems.

<sup>(source: [`man 1 fallocate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html))</sup>

And the list of supported filesystems is:

> Supported for XFS (since Linux 2.6.38), ext4 (since Linux 3.0), Btrfs (since Linux 3.7), tmpfs (since Linux 3.5) and gfs2 (since Linux 4.16).

<sup>(ibid.)</sup>

Note the list may change in the future. Check `man 1 fallocate` in your OS.

---

#### Bulk usage

The following command will run `fallocate -d` for each regular file in the current working directory and subdirectories:

```
find . -type f -exec fallocate -v -d {} \;
```

(Verbose mode (`-v`) is optional, yet useful.)

Comment: Thanks! I will try it and report back! However, i have seen that rsync when used with -S shrink also "reqular" files like avi or jpg files. These files are not already compressed? Where holes exists in such files? By curiosity i am asking.

Comment: @Estatistics I don't know. If you are sure this happens then consider asking a separate question.